# Error while running the command airflow webserver

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler, python-3.10, airflow-webserver

I am trying to run airflow apache in virtual environment in Ubuntu.

I am using the below version

1. Python 3.10.4
2. PIP 22.1
3. Airflow 2.3.0
   I have installed airflow via WSL

I am currently facing the issue when running the following command **airflow webserver**

```
ERROR - (sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to open database file
[SQL: SELECT ab_view_menu.id AS ab_view_menu_id, ab_view_menu.name AS ab_view_menu_name FROM ab_view_menu WHERE ab_view_menu.name = ?]
[parameters: ('Resources',)](Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/adminuser/airflow_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1705, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/home/adminuser/airflow_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 716, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last ):
  File "/home/adminuser/airflow_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/www/extensions/init_appbuilder.py", line 593, in _add_permissions_menu
    self.sm.add_permissions_menu(name)
[2022-05-19 16:22:13,730] {manager.py:570} ERROR - Add Permission to Role Error: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
[SQL: INSERT INTO ab_permission_view_role (permission_view_id, role_id) VALUES (?, ?)]
[parameters: (187, 1)]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/gkpj)
```

Thanks in advance for your solutions